# system.io.stream not found in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, system.io.file

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community version. I am stuck while making a C# project as I am not able to use the System.IO.Stream.

```
using System.Xml.Serialization; 
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO.Stream;
```

[Here is what it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6SVM.png)

Comment: `System.IO.Stream`, with a capital `S` in `Stream`.

Please include code in your actual question in the future, rather than a screen shot of your code.

Comment: I used even capital `S`, but it does not work either. Anyway I added a new picture showing error with. Also, thanks for your suggestion, I added the code in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# is case sensitive, the namespace is [System.IO.Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also you'll need to include `static` within the using statement as Stream is a class

```
using static System.IO.Stream;
```

Comment: `using static` came out in C# 6 (Released July 2015) - https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/16282/C6-New-Features/18096#.WZIvvlGGPZQ

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

The namespace is actually System.IO
Replace System.IO.Stream by System.IO
Stream is a class, not a namespace

Comment: This worked for me in 2017